# Semi colon separated alphanumeric

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate the below string using regular expression in Java:

```
String alphanumericList ="[\"State\"; \"districtOne\";\"districtTwo\"]";
```

I have tried the following:

```
String pattern="^\\[ (\"[\\w]\")\\s+(?:\\s+;\\s+ (\"[\\w]\")+) \\]$";
String alphanumericList ="[\"State1\"; \"district1\";\"district2\"]";
```

But the validation fails.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have additional blank spaces in your pattern.

Comment: To clarify: the start `\\[ (\"[\\w]\")` means "a bracket followed by a space followed by the group `\"[\\w]\"`. The space before the group is one of those that mastov refers to.

Comment: Additionally `\\s+;\\s+ ` would mean "at least one whitespace character before a semicolon and at least one after followed by a space". Since your input doesn't have whitespace before the semicolon it wouldn't match even without the excess spaces. Besides that there's another `\\s+` before the second group, meaning that you'd need at least 2 whitespace characters after the first semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try and mark the possible issues with your expression (issue numbers above the chars):

```
     1  4        2      3        1  4        5 1
"^\\[ (\"[\\w]\")\\s+(?:\\s+;\\s+ (\"[\\w]\")+) \\]$"
```

As you can see, there are at least 5 issues:

1. The spaces in your expression are interpreted literally, i.e. if the input doesn't contain them, it would not match. Most probably you want to remove those spaces.
2. You expect at least one whitespace character after the first group (`\\s+`), which the input doesn't seem to contain. You probably want to remove that or change the quantifier from `+` to `*`.
3. You expect at least one whitespace character before each semicolon. Together with no. 2 this would make at least two after the first group. The solution would be the same as for no. 2.
4. Your expression the strings between double quotes seems wrong. `(\"[\\w]\")+` means "a double quote, a *single* word character, a double quote" and all at least once. Besides that, `\w` is already a character class, you the brackets around that are not needed here (unless you want to add more classes or characters inside). You probably want `(\"\\w+\")` instead.
5. Additionally to 4 your non-capturing group that contains the semicolon
    (`(?:\\s+;\\s+ (\"[\\w]\")+)`) doesn't have a quantifier, i.e. it would be expected *exactly once*. You probably want to put the quantifier `+` or `*` after that group.

Another point that's not a direct issue is the capturing group around `\"[\\w]\"`. Since you seem to want to match multiple strings after semicolons you'd only be able to capture one of the matching groups. Hence you'd most probably not be able to do what you intended anyways and thus the group is not necessary.

That said the fixed original expression would look like this:

```
pattern = "^\\[(\"\\w+\")(?:\\s*;\\s+\"\\w+\")+\\]$"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas. I was pretty confused about \\w. I meant it would take care of any alphabets. But your explanation made it clear about the wrong assumption I had:)

Comment: @N3WOS `I meant it would take care of any alphabets` - just to clarify and prevent further misconception: `\w` (or `\\w` in a Java String literal) means "any _one_ character out of ascii letters, ascii digits and underscore ", i.e. it could be replaced by `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. As you can see, it doesn't take care of _any_ alphabet (meaning alphabets like the Spanish, German or even Chinese are not or at least not fully supported here).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this pattern:

```
String pattern = "\\[\\s*\"[^\"]*\"\\s*(?:;\\s*\"[^\"]*\"\\s*)*+\\]";
```

No need to add anchors since there are implicit if you use the [`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) method since this method is the more appropriate for validation tasks.

pattern details:

```
\\[         # a literal opening square bracket
\\s*        # optional whitespaces
\"          # literal quote
[^\"]*      # content between quotes: chars that are not a quote (zero or more)
\"     
\\s*
(?:         # non-capturing group:
    ;       # a literal semi-colon
    \\s*
    \"      # quoted content
    [^\"]*
    \"
    \\s*
)*+         # repeat this group zero or more time (with a possessive quantifier)
\\]         # a literal closing square bracket
```

The possessive quantifier prevent the regex engine to backtrack into repeated non-capturing groups if the closing square bracket is not present. It is a security to prevent uneeded backtracking and to make the pattern fail faster. Not that you can make possessive other quantifiers too before the non-capturing group for the same reason. [More about possessive quantifiers.](http://regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)

I decided to describe the content between quotes in this way: `\"[^\"]*\"`, but you can be more restrictive, allowing for example only words characters: `\"\\w*\"` or more general, allowing escaped quotes: `\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*+\"`

Comment: Thanks for your explanations Casimir et Hippolyte

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
static final String HEAD = "^\\[\\s*";
static final String TAIL = "\\s*\\]$";
static final String SEP = "\\s*;\\s*";
static final String ITEM = "\"[^\"]*\"";
static final String PAT = HEAD + ITEM + "(" + SEP + ITEM + ")*" + TAIL;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
pattern = "^\\[(\"\\w+\";\\s*)*(\"\\w+\")\\]$";
```

Comment: Your expression might need to be explained as well. Besides that it deviates from the original expression and might not provide everything the OP intended.